# Need to add a new column to a Dataset/Row in Spark, based on all existing columns

Tags: apache-spark

I have this (simplified) Spark dataset with these columns:

```
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"
```

And I would like to add a new column: "result".
The value of "result" is the return value of a function that takes **all** the other columns ("col1", "col2", ...) values as parameters.

map/foreach can't change the iterated row, and UDF functions don't take a whole row as a parameter, so I will have to collect **all** the column names as input, and I will also have to specify each column type in the UDF registration part.

Notes:

1. The dataset doesn't have a lot of rows, so I don't mind having a low performant solution.
2. The dataset does have a lot of columns with different types, so specifying all the columns in the UDF registration part doesn't seem like the most elegant solution.
3. The project is written in Java, so I'm using the Java API to interact with Spark.

How can I achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You actually could add a new column with a map.

```
df.map { row =>
  val col1 = row.getAs[String]("col1")
  val col2 = row.getAs[String]("col2")
  // etc, extract all your columns
  ....
  val newColumns = col1 + col2
  // do what you need to do to obtain value for a new column
  (col1, col2, ..., newColumn)
}.toDF("col1", "col2", ..., "new")
```

In term of Java API this will be just the same with some adjustments:

```
data.map((MapFunction<Row, Tuple3<String, String, String>>) row -> {
    String col1 = row.getAs("col1");
    String col2 = row.getAs("col2");
    // whatever you need
    String newColumns = col1 + col2;
    return new Tuple3<>(col1, col2, newColumns);
  }, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING()))
  .toDF("col1", "col2", ..., "new")
```

Alternatively, you could collect all your columns to the array and then process this array in your UDF.

```
val transformer = udf { arr: Seq[Any] =>
    // do your stuff but bevare of types
}

data.withColumn("array", array($"col1", $"col2", ..., $"colN"))
    .select($"col1", $"col2",..., transformer($"array") as "newCol")
```

Comment: In your solution I would still have to specify all the rows' types in this line: "Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING())". My dataset has dozens of columns, so that would be cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for my question:

```
String[] allColumnsAsStrings = dataset.columns();
final Column[] allColumns = Arrays.stream(allColumnsAsStrings).toArray(Column[]::new);

UserDefinedFunction addColumnUdf = udf((Row row) -> {
    double score;
    // Calculate stuff based on the row values
    // ...
    return score;
}, DataTypes.DoubleType
        );
dataset = dataset.withColumn("score", addColumnUdf.apply(functions.struct(allColumns)));
```